# Clone - Illegal Invocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have the following code.

```
    let root=ob[str].root;//ob is an JSON object.
    console.log(array);

    this.maping(array,str); // it is react function.

    this.number = ++number;
    ob[str].children.push(object);
    this.modified_keys[ob[str].name] = clone(ob[str]);//clone is npm module.
```

But the problem is I get the following error when run in Chrome

TypeError: Illegal invocation..clone

I cannot execute that clone. Before when I had placed **this.maping(array,str) on the same place where this code is , it ran successfully**,but now when I moved the function its giving me this error.

Comment: what's the value of obj[str] when you try to call clone ?

Comment: value is defined and is correct

Comment: Your code is weird this way. Could you do a jsfiddle ?

Comment: "Illegal Invocation" can occur when you try to clone a DOM object. You may try to prevent this by providing the depth parameter. See last comment in https://github.com/longshotlabs/simpl-schema/issues/156